# How can I hide/show a layout when a Button is pressed

Tags: android, layout

I want to hide a layout when a `Button` is pressed.

[image]

How do I do so?

Comment: You should provide the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to call

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

in your `onClick()` method where `view` is the variable name for the `View` that you are trying to make disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Try toggling the visibility to the view you want to hide or remove

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(layout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your second layout's name is `view2`, and your first buttons name is `buttonOne`:

```
buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     if(view2.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                         view2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     }else{
                         view2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     }
                }
            });
```